# Java jsoup selecting links

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to develop web scraper, I can extract all the links from a page, but I want to get some specific ones, I checked but I could not manage it as I dont have good knowledge in HTML

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Also, people will not be able to copy the HTML source when you are posting a screenshot. See here for details http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector presented in the snippet below:

```
doc.select("div.indepth-content > div.content > ul.indepth-list a")
```

---

On the screenshot, it seems you're using Chrome browser. If so, next time you can ask it to generate the CSS query for you:

1. Right click on the element you target
2. Click on "Inspect" (*a node should appear selected*)
3. Right click on this node then select <kbd>Copy</kbd> entry and <kbd>Copy selector</kbd> sub-entry

=> The CSS selector is copied in the clipboard

Please note that Chrome tends to generate (very) long CSS queries. Also, it can't generate CSS selectors for matching multiple elements.

However, if you type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> while the DevTools pane is opened and Elements tab selected, you can type a CSS selector and browse among the matched elements.

---

For more details, you can have look at the following resources:

- [JSoup CSS selector tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [JSoup CSS selector full syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [How to generate CSS selectors with Chrome Developer Tools?](http://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Element divcontent = doc.select("div.content").first();
 Element ul = divcontent.select("ul.indepth-list").first();
 ul.select("a[href]");
```

Written without editor so i can't remember if the syntax is correct.